# how to run multiple suites in RIDE

Tags: robotframework

I created multiple suites, say 'StarterKit Registration','White SIM Registration', 'Add VAS' ..etc.,
I want to run all these suites together through RIDE and I want to run in my own order i.e not in alphabatical order.

Can any one help on this to achieve.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: is it a mandate to run with RIDE?

Comment: Not mandate, i want to know whether posibility is there? if any other way is also ok. I am not aware of running multiple suites

Comment: If you run pybot with multiple suitefiles, i.e. .txts in the same folder. (pybot .), it would eventually run all the files inside that folder. Just in case you want to set priority you could either name your files as such or add an extra bit of logic to pick the files.

Comment: Hi waman, thanks for your suggestion. Actually i am not aware of how to set the priority or logic to pick the files. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: The simplest way could be to prefix your Suite names with priority value. e.g. '1_StarterKit Registration', '3_White SIM Registration', '2_Add VAS'.. So when you run "pybot ." it will pick 1,2,3 in order, just as you want.

Comment: Thanks waman, you have any idea about argumentsfile, using that also we can setup i read, but i didn't get the details, how to do that and call

Comment: can you share that link let me have a look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use prefixes to suite names as mentioned before.
Or 
as you said, Use -A arguments file which will have list of your test suites

```
Agr_sample.txt
------------------
StarterKit Registration
White SIM Registration
Add VAS
... so on
```

then pass the same argument file while triggering the pybot command as

```
pybot -A Agr_sample.txt
```

It will trigger the suites in the order they are mentioned in the file.

Hope it helps! and thanks for telling me about argument file :)